# Using Ajax Get Custom field from custom post type

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i working on slider, client ask me when someone comes on the slider image it flip and when click its video show popup, my code is working when i put into template page but when i putted it into functions.php to make shortcode it working stop. i am bit confuse with my code, because i am using custom post type slider and create i created a short code. i put my all code in functions.php file to make shortcode.

```
// Sponsor Post Type Shortcode Function

function speakers_shortcode( $atts ) { ?>
    <section class="sp_slider slider">
        <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'speakers', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 


        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="slide_div">
                    <div id="flip_wrap">
                        <div class="flip_outer">
                            <div class="vid_flip">
                                <div class="ab_flpr_inner">
                                    <div class="front_flip">
                                        <div class="sp_thumb">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="back_flip">
                                        <h2>Watch Video</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide_cntnt">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                            <a class="pop_btn rsrv_btn pink_bg white" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" onClick="popup('<?php echo $post->ID; ?>')">Make Reservation</a>
                        <div class="entry-content">
                            <?php //the_content(); ?> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            <?php endwhile;
        endif; ?>
    </section> 

<?php
}
add_shortcode( 'speaker-shortcode', 'speakers_shortcode');

this code which i am using for ajax and as well for popup
    function popup($pageid) {
  //alert($pageid);
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/getcontent.php",
    data: {
      'pageid' : $pageid
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response){
    document.getElementById("page_content_sec").innerHTML = response; //sending data to show on list
      jQuery("#page_content").show();

    }
  });
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.pop_btn').click(function(event){
        jQuery('#page_content').show();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    jQuery('#close').click(function(event){
        jQuery('#page_content').hide();
        document.getElementById("page_content_sec").innerHTML = ""; //sending data to show on list
        event.preventDefault();
    });         
});
```

Currently i tried to get title of the post to check is it things are working or not but i couldn't get

```
// here is the code which i am using on get content page
<?php 
require_once("../../../wp-config.php"); 


if(isset($_GET['pageid'])) {
    $pageid = $_GET['pageid'];
} else {
    $pageid = "";
}

//echo $pageid;
$content_post = get_post($pageid);
    $content = $content_post->post_content; ?>
        <div class="pop_hd">
                <h2 style="color: #fff;"><?php echo get_the_title($pageid); ?></span></h2>
        </div>

    <?php

die;
?>
```

Comment: What's with your username? And why are you loading `wp-config.php` - if you want to use AJAX, just follow the [How to use AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) guide.  It's different in WP, but once you get the hang of it, it's super powerful and clean.

Comment: are you asking about admin username?

Comment: No, what's with calling yourself `Stack OverFlow`.

Comment: you call me hafiz